# bootstrap button doesn't covers full text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap button doesn't covers full text. am not sure what is causing that and how can I fix it. maybe some css files in my css is overriding the styles(not sure)..how can I fix it. I tried chaging width but that is not helping here
Can anyone please assist?

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="confirmModal()">Save Selection</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the btn-sm that has a max-width, you can create a class or style it by your self with

or

.btn-width {
 width: auto
}

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why this occurs. Without providing a code demo/providing the exact custom CSS/bootstrap version. It's a hit and miss till you get it.

Try this first:

```
position: relative;
```

If that doesn't work you would surround the text in a span:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"><span style="display: block;">SAVE SELECTION</span></button>
```

All else fails, add a `style="display: inline-block;"` to the button itself

Let me know how that goes, if that doesn't work, upload the website somewhere maybe to CodePen or something and link me, from there I'll be able to look at inspect and tell you how to fix it in seconds.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, `.btn-width { width: auto }` worked.
 `<button type="button" class="btn-width btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="confirmModal()">Save Selection</button>`
CSS


 '.btn-width { width: auto !important; }'